# Trying to get Cyrillic output from Cyrillic input, all I get are?

Tags: cyrillic

Can anyone help me? I've looked here and around Google, but all the code which people claim works for them doesn't work for me. For example, if I use XeLaTeX on:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in,
 top=0.75in,  bottom=0.75in,
 inner=0.75in,outer=0.75in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\begin{center}
\huge
 Либертарианские уроки \\
\textit{Южного Парка}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\Large
Libertarian Philosophy in \\
\textit{South Park}

\vspace{\stretch{4}}
\normalsize
Брандон Симпсон
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I get the English output as normal, but the Cyrillic characters are all rendered as ??????

I thought maybe the problem was with TeXShop, but if I open the .pdf with Preview or Acrobat, it's all ???s...

Any advice? I've been using LaTeX for a long time, but haven't had to write in Cyrillic, and don't know much about fonts/encoding/etc.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I get the expected result, provided the file is saved as UTF-8. Add `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` at the beginning of the file and retry.

Answer (score 3):

To run the above code with XeLaTeX, you'd better replace the line

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

with

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
```

Also add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

to get the correct font encoding and be sure that your document is UTF-8 encoded.

Then the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in,
 top=0.75in,  bottom=0.75in,
 inner=0.75in,outer=0.75in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\begin{center}
\huge
 Либертарианские уроки \\
\textit{Южного Парка}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\Large
Libertarian Philosophy in \\
\textit{South Park}

\vspace{\stretch{4}}
\normalsize
Брандон Симпсон
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response! but the problem persists...the strange thing is, i feel like i was able to make cyrillic output as a test once before, using exactly this source. i think since then i've had to do a clean install on this machine, and now instead of that lovely Либертарианские уроки i get ????????; on the second line, the question marks are italicized, even...

Comment: Hmmm...and I don't know if this is helpful, but something very strange just happened. I found an old handout I had made in Russian. I went to typeset it using XeLaTeX. Everything worked. BUT, the characters in the source somehow turned into gibberish. So, here is the current source:\\ \section{ÐÑÐµÐŽÐžÑÐ»ÐŸÐ²ÐžÐµ}

ÐÐœÐŸÐ³ÐžÐµ ÑÑÐžÑÐ°ÑÑ, ÑÑÐŸ ÐŒÐµÑÑÐŸÐžÐŒÐµÐœÐžÑ ÐŽÐŸÐ»Ð¶ÐœÑ ÑÐ°ÑÑÐŒÐ°ÑÑÐžÐ²Ð°ÑÑÑÑ ÐºÐ°Ðº Ð¿ÐµÑÐµÐŒÐµÐœÐœÑÐµ ÑÐžÐ¿Ð°-\typ{e}:\\ and here is what that outputs: 1. Предисловие
Многие считают, что местоимения должны рассматриваться как переменные типа-⟨e⟩:

Comment: @ethan The only thing you have to do is to be sure that the encoding of the document is UTF-8.

Comment: thank you, is there more to that than adding this \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} to the preamble? if i add that, i get no error when compiling, but still a bunch of ??? instead of russian

Comment: @ethan That is to let LaTeX know that your file is UTF-8 encoded, but the encoding of your document MUST be UTF-8. I don't know how to do this in TeXShop, see its manual.

Comment: @ethan Try to add the following line at the very beginning of the document: `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode`

Comment: that worked!! i am trying to figure out if there's some option for saving what i write in texshop as utf-8, but most of what i'm reading far exceeds my capabilities. but, that commented code works, so now i can stop using word when i need russian. thanks so much

Comment: @ethan Happy about that. Remember that the best way to say thanks over here is to accept (and upvote) answers. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)